# Parsley form always fails validation on first submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have a form that I'm trying to validate with Parsley like this:

```
$('form#captainRegistrationForm').on('submit', function() {
  var $this;
  $this = $(this);
  if ($this.parsley('validate')) {
    console.log('yes');
  } else {
    console.log('no');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Unexpected behavior:

On first submit, the console always returns `no` (regardless of whether the form is valid or not). On second submit it returns `yes` (if the form is valid).

After the second submit, I purposely make the form wrong, but on the third submit, the console returns `yes`. Only after I press submit again it returns `no`.

Is there any reliable way to validate the form with Parsley? I'm using Parsley version 2.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its kind of a late respose.

However, you are not binding parsley to the form before the submit. You should do something like this:

```
// bind parsley to form
$('form#captainRegistrationForm').parsley();

// on form submit, validate the form
$('form#captainRegistrationForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    var $this;
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.parsley('validate')) {
        console.log('yes');
    } else {
        console.log('no');
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Assuming that the form exists, you should have no problems with this.

Comment: It's kinda late that I haven't said this is already resolved, Iresolve my issue with `if ($this.parsley().validate())` (this even works when i do it on submit, but i have to inject `data-parsley-validate` on the html)